# Hibernate: Criteria query taking a long time with three-level relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, relationships

I'm having trouble using Criteria to find all the objects that belong to a certain entity. My model is like the following (just showing the relevant code):

```
@Entity...
Class A {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ide_b", referencedColumnName = "ide_b", nullable = false)
    private B b;
}

@Entity...
class B {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ide_c", referencedColumnName = "ide_c", nullable = false)
    private C c;
}

@Entity...
class C {
   ...
}
```

My Criteria query is as simple as this (actually, there would be some filters, but they're not being used):

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.list(); // MY SYSTEM STAYS HERE FOREVER WHEN RUNNING AGAINST A REAL DATABASE
```

Would anybody have a clue on this issue? The system just stays forever on the line "criteria.list()" and never returns.

- I've already tested the SQL that it generates directly on the database and it works just fine.
- I've already tested this query both with code involving only class A having a reference to B and class A having a reference to C (directly). They both work. This third level in the association seems to be causing problems... Note: my Hibernate version is an old one, like 3.0.0

Comment: How about removing the `@Fetch` (and `@JoinColumn`) annotations?

Comment: I cannot remove `@JoinColumn` since I must give the names of the columns for Hibernate to map. Tried removing `@Fetch` from the relationship B -> C but it didn't work.

Comment: fetch eager is very agressive, you will receive X * Y * Z elements with X and Y duplicated as many times as necessary. Eager is only good for 1->n relations with few rows, otherwise favor Lazy getters. Lazy will send more queries, but overall it will be lighter.

Comment: I've tried setting the relationship to Lazy but it didn't work either. In addition, both the tables containing the records for B and C are really small (B has 8 rows and C has 3 rows). A has 14018 rows.

Comment: What doesn't work with Lazy exactly? Because Lazy works when you know how to use it. Also : 14018 * 8 * 3 = 336432. that's a lot of records to process.

Comment: Actually, the problems might not be related to the number of rows (see my answer bellow).

Comment: Hibernate shouldn't get stuck when loading getC(). Make sure your primary key is correctly defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove fetch type join. Eager is fine for your data layout, but do your really need that much data at once?

With default fetch, hibernate will query table A only. Then for each B's foreign key, queries B only once per key. Same done for C.

 i.e. once b_id=1 is fetched from B, it wont be fetched again even it used with million rows of A. Hibernate's 2 nd level cache handles it.

With join type fetch, for each row from A, you'll get 1 single row containing columns of all 3 tables. 

If your relation was OneToMany, then you'll get A x B x C rows returned. But since ManyToOne, there is no such issue.

Your problem is even this query returns 1 big row for each items at A, there is too much B and C replication. So DB response is huge so processing is hard as well for both DB and your app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I think the problem is something else. I've changed both relationships (A -> B and B -> C) to lazy (and removed the @Fetch). Then I queried for a specific A object. So far so good. I was able to get the object and I was able to call a.getB() successfully.

Nonetheless, when I call b.getC() Hibernate does not return the C object to me (I mean, Hibernate gets stuck at this line).

The query Hibernate creates to fetch the C object when I call b.getC() is the following:

```
 select
    myCtable0_.id as id1_85_0_,
    myCtable0_.name as nam2_85_0_ 
from
    MyTableC myCtable0_ 
where
    myCtable0_.id in (?, ?)
```

The C table has an id field (the primary key) and a name (varchar).

Comment: If that statement is not executed thousands of times, there's *no* reason the DB query should take any noticable amount of time. (Could it be that you're bumping into a breakpoint somewhere without noticing?)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I agree, there's no reason for it not to return :( Looks like a bug with the version I'm using...

Comment: Notice Hibernate is using "in (?, ?)". I don't understand why. The query should be using just the primary key ("myCtable0_.id = ?" would make more sense to me). And, yes, the mapping is correct in class C.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to fetch all data separately. Then hibernate cache will have each entity and then, I think, criteria query will be faster.